# How to write to an existing populated volume from docker-compose or docker run

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

The problem:

> I want to have a volume that is shared between a few containers. The idea is to add/write information to this shared volume when a container is initialized using docker run or docker compose(there is another way?).

My try:

I created the volume `shared-volume`:

```
docker volume create shared-volume
```

Then I want to run a new container that **must** write to that volume, if the volume is empty then the content of the `some-directory-with-content/` will be written to the volume, thats great:

```
docker run -ti --rm --mount source=shared-volume,target=/some-directory-with-content/ custom-image
```

After that when I check `shared-volume` it contains the files that were in `/some-directory-with-content/`, here is where I dont know what is the correct way to write to this `shared-volume` from docker run or docker compose.

When I tried to did the same with the second container:

```
docker run -ti --rm --mount source=shared-volume,target=/another-directory-with-content/ custom-image
```

It only returns the previous content, and I know that is the expected, so here is where I didnt know if is not possible to achieve this write to `shared-volume` using docker run or docker-compose or what is the correct way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the code that's reading and writing the files?  Except for the new-empty-named-volume case you highlight, Docker will never modify the contents of a volume, so you need some container-level code if you want volume content to be updated from an image.

Comment: > Can you show the code that's reading and writing the files? I don't get it, do you mean my Dockerfile or the content of the files ? In the second case are just nginx configurarion files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `sh` commands when you run the container. In the example below, I am creating the file `somefile` in the mount if it does not exist. I am displaying the content of the file, then I am appending *some-text* in the file.

Simply run this command several times to test it.

```
docker run \
  --rm \
  --mount source=shared-volume,target=/some-directory-with-content/ \
  alpine \
  sh -c "touch /some-directory-with-content/somefile && cat /some-directory-with-content/somefile && echo "some-text" >> /some-directory-with-content/somefile"
```

This is the expected result:

```
neo@neo-desktop:shared-vol-demo$ docker run --rm --mount source=shared-volume,target=/some-directory-with-content/ alpine sh -c "touch /some-directory-with-content/somefile && cat /some-directory-with-content/somefile && echo "some-text" >> /some-directory-with-content/somefile"
neo@neo-desktop:shared-vol-demo$ docker run --rm --mount source=shared-volume,target=/some-directory-with-content/ alpine sh -c "touch /some-directory-with-content/somefile && cat /some-directory-with-content/somefile && echo "some-text" >> /some-directory-with-content/somefile"
some-text
neo@neo-desktop:shared-vol-demo$ docker run --rm --mount source=shared-volume,target=/some-directory-with-content/ alpine sh -c "touch /some-directory-with-content/somefile && cat /some-directory-with-content/somefile && echo "some-text" >> /some-directory-with-content/somefile"
some-text
some-text
```